# Read and delete from file

Tags: shell

I have a File:

```
"testtesttestestetest /n
fromhere /n
12345698712359 /n
58981338913556 /n
125879561546621 /n
testtesttesttestestetest /n
testtesttestestetest /n
heretesttesttestestetest /n
omheretesttesttestestetest /n
fromhere /n
58981338913556 /n
125879561546621/n
12345698712359 /n
test1236547"
```

I would like to read a file and when a line matches "fromhere" I would like to delete that line and the following 3 lines.

Maybe someone has a quick solution?

Thank you!

File needs to look like this:

```
"testtesttestestetest
testtesttesttestestetest
testtesttestestetest
heretesttesttestestetest
omheretesttesttestestetest
test1236547"
```

Comment: `sed '/^fromhere/,+3d' your_file`

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Also, please read how to create a [mcve]. What you provided is only a set of requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick `sed` solution:

```
sed '/^fromhere/,+3d' /input/file
```

add `-i` to sed to do the inline edit if you need the file to be modified, and the result is what you expect:

```
sed -i '/^fromhere/,+3d' /input/file
```